# My wordpress cache plugin won't save in cache all the js css files just before the closing body tag

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching

I create my own caching plugin, but I dont succeded to save in cache correctly the full entire page

```
function checkCache() {
    $getFile = str_replace('/', ",", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if(in_array('customer-pro', $roles)) {
            $role = 'pro';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'customer' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'club';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'naya_client' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'naya';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'administrator' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'admin';
        }
    } else {
    $role = 'invite';
    }
    $isCached = file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/supercache/files/".$role."/".$getFile.'.html');
    
    if($isCached === true) {
        echo '<!--already in cache-->';
        readfile((WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/supercache/files/".$role."/".$getFile.'.html'));
        exit;
    } else {
        echo '<!--putting in cache-->';
        ob_start();
    }
}

function saveCache() {
    $getFile = str_replace('/', ",", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if(in_array('customer-pro', $roles)) {
            $role = 'pro';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'customer' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'club';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'naya_client' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'naya';
        } else if ($roles[0] == 'administrator' && count($roles) == 1) {
            $role = 'admin';
        }
    } else {
        $role = 'invite';
    }
    file_put_contents(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/supercache/files/".$role."/".$getFile.".html", ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Refresh:0");
}


add_action('wp_head', 'checkCache');


add_action('wp_footer', 'saveCache');
```

I wanna save the page in a cache file, but it does not work as expected, all the JS and CSS files just before the  tag are not saved in my cache file, why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder why you think you need to cache files that the browser will already cache for you?

Comment: Are you expecting to find CSS and JS files in your cache file system? If so, I’m not seeing any code that would download or copy them, nor anything that would parse the HTML payload to discover them

Comment: Without going into specific reasons, except to say that I once maintained a fairly popular caching plugin for WordPress that I eventually abandoned, my recommendation is to not roll your own, there are many, many, many edge cases. That said, if you do write to disk, be mindful of directory size limits as it relates to performance. I’d use a hash of the URL for the file name, and use the first 3 or 4 characters of the hash as individual subdirectories.

Comment: Also, the two hooks you are using are theme hooks, you probably would be better server by `init` and `shutdown`. Further, you might want to look into the `advanced-cache.php` drop-in if you really want performance, however you might need to get a little creative with user information